# NaN, inf or invalid value detected in endog, estimation infeasible error when training statsmodels GLM model

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression, statsmodels, glm

I am trying to build a GLM model (poisson family) using python statsmodels package on train data.
The data I have contains categorical values as exogenous variables and numerical values for my target (endegenous variable). I did standardization for numeric values and one-hot-encoding on categorical values (drop the first level). When I fit the data into the model, I got the following exceptions :

```
ValueError: NaN, inf or invalid value detected in endog, estimation infeasible.
```

When creating this model the above error raise :

```
poisson_model = sm.GLM(endog=y_train, exog=X_train_std, family=sm.families.Poisson(),offset = np.log(X_train_std.EXPOSITION))
```

But when fitting train data to see the summary output I face this error :

```
poisson_results = poisson_model.fit(method="lbfgs")
```

I have checked if there is any infinite or missing values on the train data but there is not :
[image]

Can onyone help me to resolve the problem ?

Comment: The problem comes from np.log(X_train_std.EXPOSITION) since I can not apply log function on zero values. But I don't know how to correct the error. I need to take into consideration the offset and when changing its link function to identy I get EXPOSITION in the GLM output. Any help please ?

Comment: Is it really important to have offset? Also, are you confident enough that your endogenous is Poisson-distributed? If yes, how about offset `np.log1p(EXPOSITION)`?